# Benefits of ISIC in EU (International Student Identity Card)

Tags: eu, students, czech-republic

I will have an internship in Czech Republic. I heard that with ISIC, I will have some discounts in Transports  Food / Clothes / Rental...
Can you please give me some more details?

Comment: Have you looked at [the official site of ISIC for the Czech Republic](http://www.isic.cz/en/discounts/discounts-in-the-czech-republic/)?

Comment: @svick : Yes, but as I know, personal experiences are much more relevant.

Comment: What kind of answers are you looking for that are not in the provided link? As it is, it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from what's listed [on the official ISIC site](http://www.isic.cz/en/discounts/discounts-in-the-czech-republic/?dmLimit=20&dmSeed=7443&dmDisplay=list), you can usually get a 50% discount at most Czech museums and exhibitions. Some student parties might also have free entry for those with a valid ISIC card. And some bus companies have a small discount for those with an ISIC. Nothing related to accommodation or public transport, though, as that usually requires being a local student.

So the answer is: bring it, but don't count on getting much value out of it.